# codeigniter ajax how to not auto log out users

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-2, session-cookies

I'm using CodeIgniter for a website I'm working on, because the admin area uses AJAX requests to communicate with the server. The user could be working on something that does not need AJAX requests, so after a while of non-AJAX work when the user tries to send something with AJAX, it results in an error like this:

> > SyntaxError: Unexpected token < http://www.site.com/index.php

I check whether users are logged in or not on the server like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    redirect('login');
}
```

I'm only using $_SESSION, not cookies. Do I have to use cookies or implement some JavaScript function that pings the server to keep it alive when user is idle, or both?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont be lazy use brackets in your statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't implement a solution for this error, but for however, is end up here loking for the same thing a good solution will be to use the [jQuery-Idle](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/) plugin, i hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your session expiration variables in the config file:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'yoursite';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Set the sess_expiration to something long enough that you are happy with

Comment: in the comment about the session section in the config file there's this:  `'sess_expiration' = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.`  so i set my session to this  `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;`  normally that will do it but i still get logged out.